# Making custom defined functions reactive with Shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, reactive

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   textInput("name", "What's your name?"),
   textOutput("greeting")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
   myfunc = function(text) {
      return(paste0("Hello ", text, "!"))
   }
   
   res = reactive({myfunc(input$name)})
   output$greeting <- renderText({
      res
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- Desired behavior: App renders "Hello, [input$name]!"
- Observed Behavior: Error: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'

The code works if I eliminate the function and put all of the code inside renderText. But for my actual project I have a function that creates a bunch of tables and graphs in reaction to user input, and I want to call the function only once for each renderPlot or renderTable instance.

Comment: Use `res()`, not `res` in your `renderText`. `res`refers to a reactive, `res()` refers to the reactive’s value. You can also tidy up your code elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Replacing "res" with "res()" inside renderText resulted in the desired behavior.